# Is this learning rate schedule increasing the learning rate?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, learning-rate

I was reading a PyTorch code then I saw this learning rate scheduler:

```
def warmup_lr_scheduler(optimizer, warmup_iters, warmup_factor):
    """
    Learning rate scheduler
    :param optimizer:
    :param warmup_iters:
    :param warmup_factor:
    :return:
    """
    def f(x):
        if x >= warmup_iters:
            return 1
        alpha = float(x) / warmup_iters
        return warmup_factor * (1 - alpha) + alpha

    return torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(optimizer, f)
```

and this is where the function is called:

```
if epoch == 0:
    warmup_factor = 1. / 1000
    warmup_iters = min(1000, len(data_loader) - 1)

    lr_scheduler = utils.warmup_lr_scheduler(optimizer, warmup_iters, warmup_factor)
```

As I understood it gradually increase learning rate until it reach initial learning rate. Am I correct? Why we need to increase learning rate? As I know for better learning in Neural Networks we decrease learning rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The higher (or smaller) the learning rate, the higher (or, respectively, smaller) the contribution of the gradient of the objective function, with respect to the parameters of the model, to the new parameters of the model. Therefore, if you progressively increase (or decrease) the learning rate, then you will accelerate (or, respectively, slow down) the learning process, so later training examples have higher (or, respectively, smaller) influence on the parameters of the model.

In your example, the function `warmup_lr_scheduler` returns an object of class `LambdaLR`, initialized with a certain optimizer and the function `f`, which is defined as

```
def f(x):
    if x >= warmup_iters:
        return 1
    alpha = float(x) / warmup_iters
    return warmup_factor * (1 - alpha) + alpha
```

The documentation of `torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR` says that the function `f` should compute a multiplicative factor given an integer parameter epoch, so `x` is a training epoch. If the epoch `x` is greater than or equal to `warmup_iters`, then 1 is returned, but anything multiplied by 1 is itself, so, when the epoch `x` is greater than a threshold, `warmup_iters` (e.g. 1000), then the initial learning rate is unaffected. However, when `x < warmup_iters`, the multiplicative factor is given by

```
alpha = float(x) / warmup_iters
warmup_factor * (1 - alpha) + alpha
```

which is a function of the epoch `x`. The higher the epoch `x`, the higher the value of `alpha`, so the smaller `(1 - alpha)` and `warmup_factor * (1 - alpha)`. Note that `float(x) / warmup_iters` will never be greater than 1 because `x` is never greater than `warmup_iters`. So, effectively, as the epoch increases, `warmup_factor * (1 - alpha)` tends to 0 and `alpha` tends to 1.

The learning rate can only increase if you multiply it with a constant greater than 1. However, this can only happen if `warmup_factor > 1`. You can verify this by solving the inequality `warmup_factor * (1 - alpha) + alpha > 1`.

To conclude, the initial learning rate is not being increased, but the learning process starts with a smaller learning rate than the given learning rate, for a `warmup_iters` epochs, then, after `warmup_iters` epochs, it uses the initially given learning rate (e.g. 0.002).